# IOT Central - Real Device for Production

Tags: iot, device, azure-iot-central

What devices do you use for production implementation of IOT central?

I want some kind of off the shelf, robust device (such as a temperature sensor) to put out in the field. IOT central tutorials appear to focus on POC toys, like Ardiuno and Rasberry Pi.

What is the normal approach to real-life implementations? Is the best approach to find IOT devices that allow you to import C code and use the SDK to connect? If so, where do you find such devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good starting point to find a device is to use the [Azure IoT Device Catalog](https://catalog.azureiotsolutions.com/alldevices).

Comment: This catalog and the following article cleared things up:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/preview/overview-iot-central